# how to add contacts to com.android.provider.contacts?

Tags: android, sqlite

I come up with something strange in my application that I found myself adding name,number and type of a person to android's  database.Is this possible to add the entries programmatically    to android database.I searched lot but could not find anything specific.thanks in advance.

Comment: android database means you want to add contact programatically?

Comment: yes,I want to add and delete too through my application..is it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for: [Insert, Update, Delete, View contacts in android 2.0](http://androiddevelopement.blogspot.com/2011/07/insert-update-delete-view-contacts-in.html)

And also Check the below SO Question links:

1. [Delete contact](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5513266/379693)
2. [Add contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280152/unable-to-add-contact-in-my-device)

Comment: thanks a lot.checking out the links if I could found something.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on the article from Android.
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html

There are some examples how to use the API and how to add/modify/delete contacts.
Important is the structure of the contacts.